# Native multithreading and JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have an Android application which consists of some native threads (not attached to JVM) which need to be able to call methods of a Java object.

The way in which I was intending to do this was to create a JNI function which I call from the relevant Java object which allows me to obtain and cache the required java object method ID's, JNIEnv and object references in a static native data structure so that my native threads can  (thread safely) access the required methods (e.g. using (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, this, JavaMethodID, ...), etc;

I'm not convinced this approach is going to work, since I read that the JNIEnv pointer can't be shared between threads, and that only threads which are attached to the JVM can do this kind of thing...

Is this a viable approach?

Comment: `JNIEnv` is valid only for the current thread, but `JavaVM` is global. So, save a pointer to that, as well as global references to your classes, objects, method IDs, and that will work.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 6):

1. in `JNI_OnLoad`, cache `JavaVM*`. That's the only thing persistent and valid across threads.
2. as soon as you set up some native thread, call `AttachCurrentThread` and obtain `JNIEnv*`, which is valid only for that single thread.
3. with `JavaVM*` and `JNIEnv*`, look up your `jclass`es, `jobject`s and `jmethodID`s. *These are still valid only for the single thread you have attached to.*
4. convert `jclass`es and `jobject`s to global references, so that it persists across threads. `jmethodID`s do not need to be globalized, they are not jobjects.
5. On any further native threads, you again need to call `AttachCurrentThread` to obtain a valid `JNIEnv*` for that thread.
6. Don't forget to delete the created global references when you don't need them anymore (in `JNI_OnUnload` at the latest)

Comment: Thank you Pavel, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Just to clarify, once I've cached the method ID's and globalised my class and object references, all subsequent threads can use the same methodIDs (e.g. in CallVoidMethod()) provided they do so via their own JNIEnv* as you describe in 5. I don't have to get a new set of method ID's for each thread, do I?

Comment: Yes, method ID is valid anywhere. The "globalisation" is needed only for reference types, that is anything deriving from jobject. jmethodID is not a jobject, it's an "[opaque structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.doc.html#1064)". My theory is that it's just some kind of ordinal index into the function table of the class (like vtable for C++) and hence is the same for all instances of the class.

Comment: That's great, & thanks again. I would vote your answer as 'useful', but don't yet have enough reputation.

Comment: I can wait for you having enough reputation, no problem :-)

Comment: Reading your comments it's kind of obvious, but just asking. Is a *field ID* also can be shared between threads just like method IDs, do you think (unless the class is unloaded)?

Comment: @Jenix _field ID_ is an opaque structure as _method ID_. The underlying implementation is expectedly different, but the usability across threads is the same. The link in my previous comment does not work anymore, [newer-ish here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#field_and_method_ids)

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually already sharing those across threads but JNI documentation didn't explicitly say I could use it that way, so wanted to be sure :)

Comment: @Jenix it may be better for your understanding to know what can NOT be shared between threads - sub-classes of `jobject`. [Android specific documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#local-and-global-references). By that definition, methodID and fieldID do not need any special guarding because it's just some value type, not reference type.